# Windows 10 Pro won't update from 1909

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've installed Windows 10 using an old installation ISO. I've updated to 1909, and now it says that the system is up to date. I've tried to

- update several times,
- restarting,
- running a VB script that should force an update

but it stays on 1909 saying that all is OK.

How is this possible? How can I update to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is continuing to evaluate machines (some 16 million different combinations of machines and drivers) to see when to best update any specific machine or groups of machines.

I suggest you do not force it if it is saying it is up to date.

V1909 is very current and good.

Wait for Windows Update to do its own thing. That is what we do with our machines at clients.

See what happens on Oct 13 (October Patch Tuesday)

Answer (score 1):

The system is up to date security wise. 2004 is "optional". It comes with additional features but unfortunately [with some bugs as well](https://www.gizbot.com/computer/news/do-not-install-windows-10-version-2004-update-on-your-pc-or-laptop-068023.html). Honestly I agree with John and I would wait. But if you want the features you can force the download using [Download Windows 10 page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), download the tool and follow the wizard.

Note: there are two buttons to choose from. Either the "[update now](https://exitcode0.net/how-to-force-the-windows-10-2004-update/)" (which will just download the file necessary for the upgrade) or the "download tool now" (which will give you a full ISO), see Wasif Hasan's answer for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I also honestly agree with @John and @Albin, 2004 is optional. I also run 1909 machines and VMs with making no significant difference.

But you can download the 2004 ISO (nightmare if you have slow connection, ~5 GB file), mount it, and run SETUP.exe, then choose to upgrade. This will update you to 2004 from 1909 without losing files.

[Windows 10 2004 x64 Pro Free download from official Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)

Comment: is this a different from the tool I suggested?

Comment: @Albin I suggested a method inspired from your insightful answer (+1 for that) that tonrun SETUP.exe on a different way

Comment: interesting, what's the advantage?

Comment: @Albin you won't lose your files in the partition where Windows is currently installed

Comment: ah, ok, I didn't that you loose any files "just running the update". Do you have detailed information here?

Comment: @Albin I don't have too much source, but I have seen this behavior, and one thing I can say that windows update cannot upgrade you to specific builds except the latest one, but using this method u can upgrade to any (obviously newer) builds

Comment: Ok, I see, then it's probable just an alternative to use the "upgrate button". I never heard that any files get deleted, using the "upgrade wizard" to force 2004. I'll adjust my answer, thanks.